# Adding CSS file to page with extension's init

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, onload, dom-events

I'm reading [this tutorial](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)

That is how CSS file is loaded:

```
var linkTargetFinder = function () {
    return {
        init : function () {
            gBrowser.addEventListener("load", function () {     
                // ...
                }
            }, false);
        },

        run : function () {

            var head = content.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
            style = content.document.getElementById("link-target-finder-style")

            if (!style) {
                style = content.document.createElement("link");
                style.id = "link-target-finder-style";
                style.type = "text/css";
                style.rel = "stylesheet";
                style.href = "chrome://linktargetfinder/skin/skin.css";
                head.appendChild(style);
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
}();
window.addEventListener("load", linkTargetFinder.init, false);
```

I can't understand why the CSS file can't be injected into page in `init`:

```
var linkTargetFinder = function () {
    return {
        init : function () {
            gBrowser.addEventListener("load", function () {
                var head = content.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]

                style = content.document.createElement("link");
                style.id = "link-target-finder-style";
                style.type = "text/css";
                style.rel = "stylesheet";
                style.href = "chrome://linktargetfinder/skin/skin.css";
                head.appendChild(style);

                // ...
                }
            }, false);
        },

        run : function () {
            // ...
        }
    };
}();
window.addEventListener("load", linkTargetFinder.init, false);
```

Styles just don't work in this case.
Why can't it be placed in `init`?

Comment: If you look at the Error Console you may find an error message about something being undefined or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks reasonable but for the `gBrowser` event use `DOMContentLoaded` not `load`.